# Failed installation

Tags: installation, dvd, crash

I'm installing ubuntu as my first OS on my laptop from a bootable DvD,now it all goes good,but at about 90ish % my disc starts making a weird noise and the installation crashes.Now I don't know what my problem here is,so please help!

Comment: Did you do a disk-check(press F6 when you see the purple screen when installation begins)  to see if the bootable DVD is perfectly fine?

Answer (score 1):

it sounds link a problem with the DVD itself.

Try installing Ubuntu using a USB drive.

You can make one using [UnetBootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/)